# How to make a complex string from php form?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I would like to know how this string is made

```
 [{"status":"open","open_time":"0900","close_time":"2100"},{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},{"status":"open","open_time":"0730","close_time":"2100"},{"status":"open","open_time":"0900","close_time":"2100"}]`
```

there were a checkbox, if checked open, either closed then 2 textfields that you can enter opening time and closing time respectively. After clicking on submit button, database saves this string. Can anyone please let me understand this? BTW it is in codeigniter.

Comment: It's JSON string with parameters... `json_encode(array(...))`

Comment: its' json buddy , make an array then encode it

Answer (score 1):

Create an array, and use json_encode function

```
$arr = array('lorem' => 'ipsum');
$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it comes from form first you see method if its GET or POST.

```
$string = json_encode($_POST);
$string1 = json_encode($_GET);
```